# How to handle my own function on salesforce Standard save button?

Tags: lightning

we have the requirement where we need to chenge/update valeus from our own component(Lightning) when the standard save button of salesforce is clicked .

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE! Can you let us know what have you tried so far and where are you stuck? Additionally, you might want to take a look at the Override a Standard Action on Trailhead to start with.

Comment: can you present code that you have already tried?